# StandardScaler giving error "could not convert string to float:"

Tags: python

I have a column that shows random latitude/longitude as a string in excel.

[image]

I successfully split into the training/test set but I get an error when scaling.
I am using Standard scaler to then fit into a regression model but keep getting the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which float did you mean to convert the string `'-123.048/49.1534'` to?

Answer (score 1):

I have couple of suggestions and some solutions that might fix your issue. Firstly the error "could not convert string to float" is arising due to the fact that the column "Customer_address" and "Store_address" are of type string. Standard scalar will work with float and integers, but not string. Also, the solution to the problem could be to split those "Customer_address", "Store_address"  into "Customer_address_latitude" , "Customer_address_longitude" "Store_address_latitude" , "Store_address_longitude" as float type, and then use standard scaler.

Comment: How can I make it a float type?

Comment: you cant do to Store_address directly as it has '/' . Split it and change the type via df['Store_address_latitude'].astype('float32')